# Using Wordpress custom post type to display StoryMapJS

Tags: custom-post-types, php

So I want to use [StoryMapJs](https://storymap.knightlab.com/advanced/) on my website, and I want to be able to manage these via a custom post type. I've created a custom post type and fields for each option, but I'm struggling to get them to display. My code is below:

```
<?php global $post; $post_slug = $post->post_name;
                $args=array(
                'post_type' => 'storymap_event',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
                );
            ?>

            <div id="mapdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>

            <?php $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args); $i=0;

            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $i++;
                $title = get_the_title();
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'', true);
                $latitude = intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-latitude', true));
                $longitude = intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-longitude', true));
                $caption = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-image-caption', true);
                $credit = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-image-credit', true);
                if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-image-credit', true )) { $overview = 'overview'; } else { $overview = ''; }

                $sm_array_slides = array (
                    $i => 
                      array (
                        'text' => 
                        array (
                          'headline' => $title,
                          'text' => $excerpt
                        ),
                        'location' => 
                        array (
                          'name' => 'Lime street',
                          'lat' => 53.407615,
                          'lon' => -2.977302,
                          'zoom' => 10,
                          'line' => true,
                        ),
                        'media' => 
                        array (
                          'url' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCGTR-Oa50Q',
                          'caption' => 'Example video',
                        ),
                      ),
                );

                endwhile; } wp_reset_query();

                $sm_array = array (
                  'storymap' => 
                  array (
                    'slides' => $sm_array_slides
                  ),
                );

                ?>

                <?php $json = json_encode($sm_array);?>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                var storymap_data = <?php echo $json; ?>;
                var storymap_options = {};
                var storymap = new VCO.StoryMap('mapdiv', storymap_data, storymap_options);
                window.onresize = function(event) {
                    storymap.updateDisplay(); // this isn't automatic
                }
            </script>
```

Currently this sort of works but but will only display one event. I know why I have this problem, but my poor PHP knowledge means I'm stuck on how to fix it! I somehow need to create the $sm_array_slides variable outside the loop and populate it from the storymap_event loop.

Sorry, I know this is all quite long-winded and I'm not sure I've explained very well, but I really hope someone can help because I'm pulling my hair out with it! I'm hoping it's quite a simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what happens if you create the array first and then add to it in the loop. Right now you're not adding to an array, you just keep creating it.

post_name;
                $args=array(
                'post_type' => 'storymap_event',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
                );
            ?>

```
        <div id="mapdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>

        <?php $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args); $i=0;

        $sm_array_slides = array();
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $i++;
            $title = get_the_title();
            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'', true);
            $latitude = intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-latitude', true));
            $longitude = intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-longitude', true));
            $caption = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-image-caption', true);
            $credit = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-image-credit', true);
            if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-image-credit', true )) { $overview = 'overview'; } else { $overview = ''; }

            $sm_array_slides [] = array (
                $i => 
                  array (
                    'text' => 
                    array (
                      'headline' => $title,
                      'text' => $excerpt
                    ),
                    'location' => 
                    array (
                      'name' => 'Lime street',
                      'lat' => 53.407615,
                      'lon' => -2.977302,
                      'zoom' => 10,
                      'line' => true,
                    ),
                    'media' => 
                    array (
                      'url' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCGTR-Oa50Q',
                      'caption' => 'Example video',
                    ),
                  ),
            );

            endwhile; } wp_reset_query();

            $sm_array = array (
              'storymap' => 
              array (
                'slides' => $sm_array_slides
              ),
            );

            ?>

            <?php $json = json_encode($sm_array);?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var storymap_data = <?php echo $json; ?>;
            var storymap_options = {};
            var storymap = new VCO.StoryMap('mapdiv', storymap_data, storymap_options);
            window.onresize = function(event) {
                storymap.updateDisplay(); // this isn't automatic
            }
        </script>
```

you may need to pull the extra `array (` out on this line:

`$sm_array_slides [] = array (`  (and don't forget the trailing `)`)

But i don't know the array format your map is looking for so i didn't remove it in my code.